# Consumer-producer pattern with pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, redis, pyarrow

What is the best way to implement a multi process based consumer producer pattern with pyarrow as a fast memory store for pandas dataframes?

Currently I am using redis pub sub but I think there might be a more efficient (faster) solution? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with lists:

Producer puts data into a list with `LPUSH`
Consumer takes data from this list with `RPOP` or `BRPOP` (blocking).

Limitations: only one consumer reads the message. If you have 2, only one of them will see the message.

Speed: for one pair of consumer-producer it will have the same speed. The more consumers (for this or other lists), the faster it will be than pub/sub.

Comment: thanks! I was also kinda looking to avoid redis and was hoping that there is some arrow inherent functionality I was not aware of but this would work just fine!